# Getting segmentation fault while printing output

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am trying to know how the array in c is working. so i was implementing some basic array concepts. when i run the program i got the exact output but at the end of the output it says **segmentation fault**.

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {};
    printf("Enter the number:");
    int n = get_int();
    int m = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("insert:");
        m = get_int();
        a[i] = m;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a[j]);
    }

}
```

output:

```
Enter the number:3
insert:1
insert:2
insert:3
1
2
3
~/workspace/ $ ./arr_test
Enter the number:5
insert:1
insert:2
insert:3
insert:4
insert:5
1
2
3
4
5
Segmentation fault
```

see for the first output it has a size of 3 it doesn't show `segmentation fault` but for second one it has a size of 5 it shows. so why its happening and what mistake i made.

Comment: `int a[] = {};` is an error in Standard C. I recommend operating your compiler in standard-compliant mode, so you get errors at compile-time instead of run-time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory for the array.  Something like:

```
int main(void)    {
   int *a;
   ...
   int n = get_int();
   ...
   a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   if (!a) {
      // Add error handling here
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of the array you want to make ahead of time, declare it like `int a[128];` instead of just `int a[];` so `a` at indices `0` to `127` will be safe to write to (and subsequently read from).

If you want to declare an array of size `n` at runtime, use `int a[] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));` or `int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));`. Make sure `a` is not `NULL` before using it, and remember to call `free(a);` when you are done with it to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: i allocated size of a to 128 bits now its doesn't show `segmentation fault`. but how do i make `a` to allocate it's own size.

Comment: You did not allocate a size of 128 *bits*. You allocated 128 * 4 bytes.